# selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #passwordNext

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver, exception, waits

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #passwordNext
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'BRIGHTLEAF-0046', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 9752, moz:profile: C:\Users\Priti Raut\AppData..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 7982cff0-6252-4eae-9a37-68aa3b6ef83e
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=passwordNext}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
```

**Code:**

```
package scripts;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class google 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Priti Raut\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");     

        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("my username"); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();    
        System.out.println("identifier next");
        //driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("my password");
        System.out.println("password next");
        driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
        System.out.println("click next");
        driver.quit();
    }       
}
```

I tried using className as well as using name attribute, but system doesn't accept value for password and next button of password.

Comment: Please share the HTML of the page, so that proper help can be provided.

Comment: Related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium

Answer (score 1):

As per the Stack Trace

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #passwordNext
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'BRIGHTLEAF-0046', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 9752, moz:profile: C:\Users\Priti Raut\AppData..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 7982cff0-6252-4eae-9a37-68aa3b6ef83e
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=passwordNext}
```

The element `passWordNext` is not able to be located. If you're using a CSS Selector, then use `input#passWordNext` otherwise if you're using the `id` locator, just use `passWordNext` (without the `#`), and wait for some time (preferably using an `Explicit Wait`).

Answer (score 0):

There can be a couple reasons to check:

- Check if the locating strategy is correct.
- Check if the element is present in the current top level browsing context.(esp. if it is present inside a frame)
- Sync issue

Answer (score -1):

Use `thread.sleep()` before the password field then this will work..

Else use **implicitly Wait** command before the password field:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Do not use `thread.sleep();` This is not a good practice, and your test **ALWAYS** is flaky. Instead use **explicit wait.**

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov - I am sorry that mods converted your correct answer to a comment to an incorrect answer, but this is how it is: "Life is not fair, and then you die" :-) Hang around and try again next time. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The error is because either the element is dead, due to page refresh or webdriver is unable to locate/it at the specified path before it moves on, so use `thread.sleep()` method, which will wait for a pre-defined time before throwing an error.

for `thread.sleep` read [this tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Further recommended reading [seleniumhq.org site.](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)